# JPA (Hibernate) - ManyToMany - setter

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I am not sure if I am doing something wrong, but when I have these two entities:

```java
@Setter @Getter @NoArgsConstructor @FieldDefaults(level = AccessLevel.PRIVATE)
@Entity
@Table(name = "GROUP_OF_USERS")
public class Group {
    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    Long id;
    String name;
    @ManyToOne
    User administrator;
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "groups", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    Set<User> users = new HashSet<>();

    public void setAdministrator(User user){
        this.administrator = user;
        addUser(user);
    }

    public void addUser(User user){
        users.add(user);
    }

}

@Entity
@Setter @Getter @NoArgsConstructor @FieldDefaults(level = AccessLevel.PRIVATE)
@Table(name = "APP_USER")
public class User {
    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    Long id;
    String name;
    @Column(unique = true)
    String email;
    String password;
    String bankAccount;
    boolean isActive = false;
    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(
            name = "GROUP_USER_RELATIONSHIP",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "group_id"))
    Set<Group> groups = new HashSet<>();

    public void addGroup(Group group){
        groups.add(group);
    }

}
```

and service method like this:

```java
@Override
    public Group crateGroup(String userName, String groupName) {
        var userInDb = userRepository.findUserByEmailIgnoreCase(userName).orElseThrow(() -> new UserNotFoundException(userName));

        userInDb.getGroups().stream()
                .filter(group -> group.getName().equals(groupName))
                .findAny()
                .map(Group::getName)
                .ifPresent(name -> {throw new GroupUniqueConstrainException(name);});

        var newGroup = new Group();
        newGroup.setName(groupName);
        newGroup.setAdministrator(userInDb);

        return groupRepository.save(newGroup);
    }
```

than I am surprised that administrator is set in DB, but join table doesn't contain any record. Could someone help me here to understand where could be a problem? I found out that I could update the `addUser` method so it would also add group to the user. But I would need to do this also for `addGroup` method in User class so when calling that it would create infinite loop.

Comment: You have `mappedBy = "groups"` which means that the `User` entity owns the relationship. Changes in a relationship will only be persisted by the owner, so you have to use the `userRepository`.

Comment: You explicitly have to add users to groups / groups to users. Otherwise you have empty collections and thus nothing is saved in the database. You should keep getter / setter clean from any logic and call the add methods separately.

Comment: @XtremeBaumer should this logic be part of the entity or part of the service layer?